# Samsung "Smart stay" for Windows laptop

Tags: webcam, laptop-display

Samsung uses technology named "Smart stay" on their Android devices (Samsung Galaxy S III):

> It waits till you're asleep: the screen maintains a bright display as long as you're looking at it.
>   [Samsung Smart stay](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxys3/smartstay.html)

Is there software to achieve the same behavior on a Windows laptop? Simply put, the software should use the webcam of the laptop and turn the screen off if there was nobody watching the display.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to prevent screen saver based on looking at the screen. If you find something please text me ;)

Comment: I am also looking for the same Smart Stay feature, Windows 7 or 8.1 don't have it. I have suggested they have Smart Stay for all Windows OSs, at Microsoft Answer Desk. The person I chatted with didn't have an excellent command of the English language. He also kept trying to sell me things like Windows 8.1 or a subscription, and it was confusing because it wasn't clear what he was asking. E.g., he asked: "You want to process Windows 8.1?" He was actually asking if I wanted to update to Windows 8.1, when I never suggested that. I asked Jerico to pass my suggestion onto the development team, and